# Error Occurred while importing android project from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle

I'm facing the following error when importing my Android project from Eclipse to Android Studio.

> Project Girls Hair Styles Selfie:D:\android\Girls Hair Styles
>   Selfie\project.properties:
>
> Library reference ..\android-support-v7-appcompat could not be found
>   Path is D:\android\Girls Hair Styles
>   Selfie..\android-support-v7-appcompat which resolves to
>   D:\android\android-support-v7-appcompat

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Send a complete code including Gradle.build file.
AppCompat is the newer version in Android Studio which was used as ActionBarSherlock(ABS) in Eclipse.

Make sure to import module ABS while building. 
Since Eclipse did not have gradle files, there could also be some errors in the gradle configurations.

Update your question and send the Gradle as well as the Java file where Error is appearing.

Comment: This is the actual error and I don't have any gradle file because I'm importing the source code from my Eclipse workspace to Android Studio using Android Studio import wizard. I don't know where and why the error is coming?